# Intermittent disconnect failure in IdTCPServer under Linux

Tags: linux, delphi, indy10, tcpserver

I had to start a new Question as the system refuses me to re-open the original question.

The IdTCPServer intermittently fails to disconnect a Client, that is, it stays in the Context list.
It happens when a Client is no longer responding to a 'ping' from the Server. The Client is in fact already off-line, but the Server is not aware of this until the timeout occurs, and the "DisconnectClient" is called, as per code below.

```
function DisconnectClient(Call: string; Server: TDTBPort):boolean;
var
  Index: integer;
  List: TIdContextList;
  i: integer;
begin
  Result := false;
  
  if Server = dpOne
  then List := IdTCPServer1.Contexts.LockList
  else List := IdTCPServer2.Contexts.LockList;
  try
    try
      Index := -1; 
      for i := 0 to List.Count-1 do
      begin
        if TDTBClient(List[i]).Callsign = Call then
        begin
          inc(TDTBClient(List[i]).TryDisconnect);
          Index := i;
          break;
        end;
      end;

      if Index >= 0 then
      begin
        result := true;
        Log('DisconnectClient: Disconnecting: Callsign='+Call+'  Port='+integer(Server).ToString+'. Index='+Index.ToString);

        // TIdContext(List[Index]).Connection.Disconnect;    
        TIdContext(List[Index]).Connection.Socket.Binding.CloseSocket;
      end else
      begin
        try
          Log('DisconnectClient: Client not found in List Port '+integer(Server).ToString+': '+Call,d_warning);
        except
          // It may now be invalid.
        end;
      end;


    except
      on E:Exception do Log('DisconnectClient: '+E.Message,d_error);
    end;
  finally
    if Server = dpOne then IdTCPServer1.Contexts.UnlockList else
    if Server = dpTwo then IdTCPServer2.Contexts.UnlockList;
  end;
end;
```

I have added a load of debug log entries through the Indy10 system.
As per Remy's advice, I now call Connection.Socket.Binding.CloseSocket instead of Connection.Disconnect.
However, today the intermittent problem happened again, and this time I could see the code in CloseSocket never executed, and it looks like it got stuck trying to enter "FConnectionHandle.Enter"

```
procedure TIdSocketHandle.CloseSocket;
begin
  FConnectionHandle.Enter;
  try
    if HandleAllocated then
    begin
      // Bart
      syslog(LOG_NOTICE, 'IdSocketHandle.CloseSocket: HandleAllocated');
      // Must be first, closing socket will trigger some errors, and they
      // may then call (in other threads) Connected, which in turn looks at
      // FHandleAllocated.
      FHandleAllocated := False;
      syslog(LOG_NOTICE, 'IdSocketHandle.CloseSocket calls Disconnect');
      Disconnect;
      SetHandle(Id_INVALID_SOCKET);
    end else syslog(LOG_NOTICE, 'IdSocketHandle.CloseSocket: NOT HandleAllocated');
  finally
    FConnectionHandle.Leave;
  end;
end;
```

None of the 'CloseSocket' Syslog entries were called during this event last night, despite the fact I just called "TIdContext(List[Index]).Connection.Socket.Binding.CloseSocket".

This means it never got past the "FConnectionHandle.Enter".  Which is almost impossible, as this is only used *twice*: Once during Connect, and then during Disconnect. I have not been able to find any other references to this CriticalSection in the Indy code.
Or, the whole 'Socket' was already invalid? But then I would have expected some Exception. And the log was clean for the last 12 hours.
The specific Client was *not* disconnected before.

Then the Timeout system then keeps calling DisconnectClient, which calls CloseSocket. But it never got inside the CloseSocket code.
Last night, after 169 times of this, the entire application died under Linux, directly after that last call to CloseSocket.
No other Log entries. Also not from the Kernel.
One moment it was there, the next moment the application had disappeared.

Any advice is welcome.  I am desperate to get this fixed.

Comment: "*I had to start a new Question as the system refuses me to re-open the original question*" - the original question is not closed. But even if it were close, as the asker, you should be able to freely edit it (though, at your reputation level, edits must be at least 6 characters). You were making edits before, why stop?

Comment: "*I have not been able to find any other references to this CriticalSection in the Indy code. Or, the whole 'Socket' was already invalid?*" - you are probably calling `CloseSocket` on an invalid object. "*But then I would have expected some Exception*" - accessing an invalid object does not guarantee an Exception is raised. It is **undefined behavior**, anything could happen.

Comment: In any case, StackOverflow is a Q&A site, it is not the place to discuss library bugs and seek fixes. If you feel this is a genuine bug, you should open a ticket in Indy's [issue tracker](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/issues) on GitHub. And there are actual discussion forums for Indy on [Delphi-PRAXIS](https://en.delphipraxis.net/forum/35-indy/) and [AToZed](https://atozed.com/forums/forum-9.html) servers.

Comment: Okay, I will do all that then. Thanks.